# Ever maximized form VC++

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

How can i create a ever maximized form that can't be resized or restored?
I tried with:

```
    this->WindowState = System::Windows::Forms::FormWindowState::Maximized;
    this->MaximizeBox = false;
```

But if I click on the form bar and then I drag, it is restored, also if I double click on it's bar it is restored.

Can you help me?

Comment: Don't set the WindowState, just set the Size from the Screens class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::None;
```

The Titlebar and borders will disappear this way, and your application will appear full screen.

Or, if you want to keep the title bar :

```
        WindowState = FormWindowState::Normal;
        this->Width = Screen::FromControl(this)->Bounds->Width;
        this->Height = Screen::FromControl(this)->Bounds->Height;
        this->WindowState = FormWindowState::Maximized;
        this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::FixedSingle;
```

Users will still be able to drag the window though (that's what the titlebar is for).
You might want to set MaximizeBox = true then, so that the user can easily restore full screen if the window was dragged somewhere else.

If you want to prevent the user from moving the window, you could assign an eventhandler to the `Move` event of your window and set the WindowState to maximized again.

Comment: thanks, but isn't there anyway to disable the resize on dragging the toolbar? because my application is designed only for fullscreen...

Comment: Then you need to capture mouse events. Or just use the first solution and create your own Title bar. What do you need it for anyway if you don't want anyone to use it? It sounds like a Label containing the application name would be enough, too. And maybe a small button closing the app.